# Is there a difference in behaviour of mp.Process subclass vs mp.Process with a target funciton in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, unix, multiprocessing

I am trying to implement a producer-consumer based solution using threads within a subprocess in python. When I try to subclass `mp.Process`, both producer and consumer threads block forever but everything works as expected when using target function in `mp.Process` to achieve the same functionality. Can anyone please explain this disparity?

Minimal example using target function:

```
import queue
import multiprocessing as mp
import threading


class Worker(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, output_queue):
        super().__init__()
        self.queue = output_queue

    def run(self):
        for i in range(3):
            print('producer executing queue.put', flush=True)
            self.queue.put(i)
            print('producer queue.put successful', flush=True)
        
        self.queue.put(None)


def gen():
    output_queue = queue.Queue(1)
    Worker(output_queue).start()

    while True:
        print('consumer executing queue.get', flush=True)
        x = output_queue.get()
        if x is None:
            break

        print(x, flush=True)
        print('consumer queue.get successful', flush=True)
    print('finished')


if __name__=='__main__':
    mp.Process(target=gen).start()
```

Output:

```
producer executing queue.put
consumer executing queue.get
producer queue.put successful
0
consumer queue.get successful
producer executing queue.put
consumer executing queue.get
producer queue.put successful
producer executing queue.put
1
consumer queue.get successful
consumer executing queue.get
producer queue.put successful
2
consumer queue.get successful
consumer executing queue.get
finished
```

Same example with mp.Process subclass

```
import queue
import multiprocessing as mp
import threading


class Worker(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, output_queue):
        super().__init__()
        self.queue = output_queue

    def run(self):
        for i in range(3):
            print('producer executing queue.put', flush=True)
            self.queue.put(i)
            print('producer queue.put successful', flush=True)
        
        self.queue.put(None)


class Generator(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.output_queue = queue.Queue(1)
        Worker(self.output_queue).start()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            print('consumer executing queue.get', flush=True)
            x = self.output_queue.get()
            if x is None:
                break

            print(x, flush=True)
            print('consumer queue.get successful', flush=True)
        print('finished')


if __name__=='__main__':
    Generator().start()
```

Output:

```
producer executing queue.put
producer queue.put successful
producer executing queue.put
consumer executing queue.get
0
consumer queue.get successful
consumer executing queue.get
[Program gets stuck here]
```

[Edit]: I am running this with python 3.7 and the following also works:

```
import queue
import multiprocessing as mp
import threading


class Worker(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, output_queue):
        super().__init__()
        self.queue = output_queue

    def run(self):
        for i in range(3):
            print('producer executing queue.put', flush=True)
            self.queue.put(i)
            print('producer queue.put successful', flush=True)

        self.queue.put(None)


def gen(output_queue, worker):
    worker.start()

    while True:
        print('consumer executing queue.get', flush=True)
        x = output_queue.get()
        if x is None:
            break

        print(x, flush=True)
        print('consumer queue.get successful', flush=True)
    print('finished')


if __name__=='__main__':
    output_queue = queue.Queue(1)
    mp.Process(target=gen, args=(output_queue, Worker(output_queue))).start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Booboo's answer doesn't explain the blocking issue (and it's not specific to MacOS), I am adding this answer for anyone interested.

In 2nd version of the code, the following sequence of events occur which explain the blocking:

1. In main process, `Generator()` calls `Generator.__init__()` for initialisation of consumer. During this initialisation, `output_queue` in created  and `Worker` (producer thread) is started. Since this is all done by main process, producer starts filling the queue in main process's memory space.
2. Then `Generator.start()` is called which starts the consumer process and in doing so creates a copy of main process's memory space. While creating this copy, the `output_queue` from main's memory is also copied in whatever state it is (can be empty, filled or partially filled depending on how many elements producer was able to put till this time). Since `output_queue` is a not a multiprocessing queue, the new copy doesn't share memory with the original one. Reference for how fork (default process creation in unix) works: https://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411.ck/www/NOTES/process/fork/create.html
3. At this point, `Worker` (producer thread) is running in main's memory space and keeps trying to put elements to the queue in that space (since the queue size is limited to 1, put call blocks).
4. Also, `Generator` (consumer process) keeps trying to read from `output_queue` copy in its own memory. Since this copy was cloned as it is from main's copy when consumer was created, consumer is able to get 1 element out of the queue (which in this case is the number of elements producer was able to produce before the copy was created). After reading this 1 element, the `get` call in consumer blocks since the queue in it's memory space is now empty.

So in summary, there are two different copies of `output_queue`: 1 in main's memory space to which producer writes to, and other in consumer's memory space from which consumer reads. Since the 2nd is cloned from 1st when 1 element was already there, consumer is able to access that element.

To further add, even 3rd version of code has 2 copies of `output_queue` but since the producer in 3rd version is started in consumer's memory space (in `gen` function), both are writing to and reading from the `output_queue` in same memory.

To conclude, 1st version of code is probably the best thing to do since it keeps producer and consumer threads in same memory and also avoids creating unnecessary copy of the queue in main's memory. `mp.Queue` can also be used to avoid all these issues as Booboo mentioned, but the unnecessary use of shared memory can be avoided by using the 1st version in the first place since queue is never accessed in main.

Another option is to use 2nd version (if subclassing is required) but start the producer inside `run` function so that it's running in consumer's memory space which would make it equivalent to 1st version:

```
class Generator(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        self.output_queue = queue.Queue(1)
        Worker(self.output_queue).start()

        while True:
            print('consumer executing queue.get', flush=True)
            x = self.output_queue.get()
            if x is None:
                break

            print(x, flush=True)
            print('consumer queue.get successful', flush=True)
        print('finished')


if __name__=='__main__':
    Generator().start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your two examples are *not* equivalent. In the first code example, when you use the *target* argument, function `gen` is called as a result of the `Process.start` method, which normally invokes `run`, and seeing that *target=gen* has been specified it then delegates to your `gen` function, which acts as the `run` method. But in the second code example, when you subclass `Process`, you have now moved the following statements:

```py
        self.output_queue = queue.Queue(1)
        Worker(self.output_queue).start()
```

from what was logically the `run` method to the `Process.__init__` method. If you move it back to `run` as follows, you will have a truly equivalent program and it will work:

```py
class Generator(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


    def run(self):
        output_queue = queue.Queue(1)
        Worker(output_queue).start()
        while True:
            print('consumer executing queue.get', flush=True)
            x = output_queue.get()
            if x is None:
                break

            print(x, flush=True)
            print('consumer queue.get successful', flush=True)
        print('finished')
```

Prints:

```
producer executing queue.put
consumer executing queue.get
producer queue.put successful
0
producer executing queue.put
consumer queue.get successful
producer queue.put successful
consumer executing queue.get
producer executing queue.put
1
producer queue.put successful
consumer queue.get successful
consumer executing queue.get
2
consumer queue.get successful
consumer executing queue.get
finished
```

So the question remains "Why didn't your second example work as is?". It's because your `__init__` method created a `Thread` instance and when it did it was created while you were still executing in the main process's address space. But when the `start` method is executed, it now becomes necessary to serialize/de-serialize with `pickle` that thread to the new address space that the `Process` instance's `run` method will actually be executing in. The problem is that **a Thread instance cannot be pickled.**:

> TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object

Perhaps you were running under Jupyter Notebook or some other environment and did not see this message on the log.

**Update**

I tried your code on Python 3.6 (Windows) and still got the pickle error. I then ran this under Python 3.7 under Linux and got the same results as you did. So the type of error you get is also platform dependent (whether fork is being used to create new processes?). It appears that you cannot pass 'queue.Queue` instances from one process to another regardless of Python release or platform.

Comment: Yes I noticed the non-equivalence later. But I was running this as a script and still there was no error. I am not sure about the pickling issue (I don't see any error and even if there's an error, it doesn't explain the blocking) but this has given me an idea of possible sequence which could explain:

1. Producer starts in the main process and fills the queue.
2. Consumer is started and makes copy of (now filled or partially filled) queue.
3. Producer and consumer  now are both working on different copies of queue (one in main and other in consumer process) causing both to block.

Comment: I got the above exception running Python 3.8.5 -- your version may be different and the non-equivalence may manifest itself differently. You were comparing apples and oranges because one way or another there is no denying that in the second coding example the thread *and* queue have to be serialized/deserialized from one process to another. What happens if you used instead a `multiprocessing.Queue` instance?  Of course, you would still be comparing apples and oranges. But I think you are just wasting time because what you are doing is *verboten*, certainly on Python 3.8.

Comment: You are right, I was running this in python 3.7 and this is not allowed in python 3.8 and above. But as far as the error is concerned, python 3.7 doesn't have any problems running this. In fact you can send thread as an argument to a process's target function in python 3.7 and it runs fine (gives the same error in 3.8+). So I think the right explanation for this code not working for 3.7 would be what I wrote in the comment. Anyway, I have accepted your answer because it's right for python 3.8+. Can I add the argument for python 3.7 as an augmentation to your answer to complete it?

Comment: I have added an **Update** to the question that will be illuminating.

Comment: Yes I was running this on MacOS (unix basically). But using `multiprocessing.Queue` is an alternate solution. What I was looking for wasn't a solution but an explanation. :) Basically it works as long as you start the producer in consumer's memory space (since it's not `mp.Process` which is shared between processes as well). Since the 2nd version starts the producer in main's memory space, the queue in main's memory space is being filled and not the one consumer has access to.

Comment: I rejected your edit because I didn't think it explained why the process is able to retrieve one message from the queue. When you make an edit both of our names are on the answer and it's not clear to the casual reader which one of us is saying what without looking at the edit history. So add what you want to say as one or more comments.

Comment: It does explain. As I wrote, state of queue depends on exactly when the copy of main's memory is copied. Since the size of queue is fixed and the producer is fast, the queue is full when the consumer creates main's copy and thus is able to excess only those elements which were already in the queue when the copy was created. I don't have problems adding in comments but without this argument, the actual question remains unanswered and so the answer is not complete.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235489/discussion-between-booboo-and-abhinav-goyal).